# jq + update json file and append name according to ID number

Tags: linux, json, jq

We want to edit the json file according to the following rule

We need to generate the name `car0X_hyb.com`  - under `mazda`  string ( while X is the ID number )

we need to update the json file on our linux machine

Example -  `ID=1`

Then json will be as

```
{
  "toyota": [
    "car1.com"
  ],
  "mazda": [
    "car01_hyb.com"
  ],
  "ford": [
    "car01_eng.com"
  ]
}
```

`ID=4` , Then json will be as

```
{
  "toyota": [
    "car1.com"
  ],
  "mazda": [
    "car01_hyb.com",
    "car02_hyb.com",
    "car03_hyb.com",
    "car04_hyb.com"
  ],
  "ford": [
    "car01_eng.com"
  ]
}
```

`ID=6` , Then json will be as

```
{
  "toyota": [
    "car1.com"
  ],
  "mazda": [
    "car01_hyb.com",
    "car02_hyb.com",
    "car03_hyb.com",
    "car04_hyb.com",
    "car05_hyb.com",
    "car06_hyb.com"
  ],
  "ford": [
    "car01_eng.com"
  ]
}
```

`ID=10` , Then json will be as

```
{
  "toyota": [
    "car1.com"
  ],
  "mazda": [
    "car01_hyb.com",
    "car02_hyb.com",
    "car03_hyb.com",
    "car04_hyb.com",
    "car05_hyb.com",
    "car06_hyb.com",
    "car07_hyb.com",
    "car08_hyb.com",
    "car09_hyb.com",
    "car10_hyb.com"
  ],
  "ford": [
    "car01_eng.com"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why `"car03_hyb.com"` is duplicated?

Comment: sorry - typo mistake

Comment: Before editing, does `"mazda"` key exist within json file? if so, what's its content?

Comment: ... and if non-empty, do you want that content to be overwritten by the new elements, or appended to?

Comment: do you want that content to be overwritten by the new elements - YES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a non-ugly way to zero-pad the IDs, but given

```
$ jq '.' file.json
{
  "toyota": [
    "car1.com"
  ],
  "mazda": [
    "foo.bar"
  ],
  "ford": [
    "car01_eng.com"
  ]
}
```

then for example for `ID` = `11`:

```
$ jq --arg ID 11 '
    .mazda |= [range(1;($ID | tonumber)+1) as $ID | if $ID < 10 then "car0\($ID)_hyb.com" else "car\($ID)_hyb.com" end]
' file.json
{
  "toyota": [
    "car1.com"
  ],
  "mazda": [
    "car01_hyb.com",
    "car02_hyb.com",
    "car03_hyb.com",
    "car04_hyb.com",
    "car05_hyb.com",
    "car06_hyb.com",
    "car07_hyb.com",
    "car08_hyb.com",
    "car09_hyb.com",
    "car10_hyb.com",
    "car11_hyb.com"
  ],
  "ford": [
    "car01_eng.com"
  ]
}
```

---

Or (perhaps this is better) generate and format the complete string elements in the shell, and pass that as an `argjson`:

```
jq --argjson IDS '['"$(seq -s, -f'"car%02.0f_hyb.com"' 11)"']' '
  .mazda |= $IDS
' file.json
```

Comment: zero-pad the IDs should be only for mazda , all others should be the same

Comment: well done really excellent

Comment: instead of hyb.com we want to set variable as $domain , can you please update another answer how to set the variable